# Cannot bind event callbacks on DOM objects under a directive's DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I'm currently trying to refactor some very simple AngularJS code to move all functionality under a top-level directive. A parent element is given the directive, the directive binds the 'mousemove' event to that element, then goes through each child with a particular ID and binds 'mousedown' and 'mouseup' event callbacks to it.

```
angular.module('DataStructureVisualizer').
directive('dragDrop', function () {

  return {
      link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        var mouseLocX = 0;
        var mouseLocY = 0;
        var isElementHeldDown = false;
        var elementHeldDown;
        var heldDownElementWidth = 0;
        var heldDownElementHeight = 0;

    //Bind callback to get mouse position
    $scope.captureCoordinate = function($event) {
        mouseLocX = $event.x;
        mouseLocY = $event.y;

        if(isElementHeldDown == true) {
            elementHeldDown.css('position', 'absolute');
            elementHeldDown.css('left', mouseLocX - heldDownElementWidth / 2 + 'px');
            elementHeldDown.css('top', mouseLocY - heldDownElementHeight / 2 + 'px');
        }
    }

    var dragDroppables = element[0].querySelectorAll('#DragDroppable');

    for (var elementIdx = 0; elementIdx < dragDroppables.length; elementIdx++) {
        var bindElement = dragDroppables[elementIdx];

        bindElement.on('mousedown', function() {
            element.css('background-color', 'rgb(17, 83, 252)');            
            elementHeldDown = element;
            isElementHeldDown = true;

            var style = window.getComputedStyle(element[0]);           
            heldDownElementWidth = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('width'));
            heldDownElementHeight = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('height'));     
        });
        bindElement.on('mouseup', function () {
            element.css('background-color', 'rgb(73, 122, 255)');
            isElementHeldDown = false;
        });
    }
```

I'm able to bind perfectly fine to element, but when using element.querySelectorAll and going through the returned list of elements, it comes back and says "bindElement.on() is not a function"

Here's the HTML side:

```
  <div id="DragDropArea" ng-mousemove="captureCoordinate($event)" drag-drop>
      <!-- <div>x: {{x}}</div>
      <div>y: {{y}}</div> -->
      <div id="DragDroppable">
        <div line-draw>64</div>
      </div>
      <div id="DragDroppable">
        <div line-draw>64</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is because `bindElement` is an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), not a jQuery or jqLite style object .

Comment: I believe `angular.element(bindElement).on('mousedown', function() {`... would work (without having tested your directive above)

Comment: @davidkonrad That worked - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That answer lied in the fact that when grabbing the child elements, it's returning a NodeList of Elements, when they need to be jQuery or jqLite style objects. Changing

```
bindElement.on('mousedown', function() {...
```

To

```
angular.element(bindElement).on('mousedown', function() {...
```

Fixed the problem.